# ¿Cómo puedo agrupar elementos de una lista con ciertas condiciones?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, agrupación

Tengo un json con 140 de estos elementos ('activities') y necesito hacer un programa en python para que se transforme a esto ('user_sessions').
Es decir, que ahora en vez de estar agrupado por el id de la actividad y la demás información, ahora se agrupe por 'user_id' con ciertas condiciones:

1. Añadir la duración de la sesión en segundos (answered_at- first_seen_at)
2. El id de las actividades que realizó (un usuario) durante esa sesión debe aparecer al final y no al principio (como en 'activities')
3. Si pasan más de cinco minutos entre 'first_seen_at' y 'answered_at', cuenta como una nueva sesión.

Mi pregunta es, ***¿cómo puedo agrupar por id de usuario y revisar todos los datos dentro de un mismo id para hacer que cumpla con las condiciones de arriba?***

Había usado una función lambda para acomodar por user_id  `data['activities'].sort(key=lambda x: x['user_id'])` pero literalmente solo lo acomoda por user_id y necesito agruparlo por user_id.

Hasta ahorita este es mi código, no sé si sirva de mucho:

```
import json
import datetime


with open('/Users/kenyacastellanos/Downloads/data.json') as json_data_file:
    data = json.load(json_data_file)

data['activities'].sort(key=lambda x: x['user_id'])    

for x in range(len(data["activities"])):
    #print("New Order:", data['activities'][:])

    date1 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(data['activities'][x]['answered_at'])
    date2 = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(data['activities'][x]['first_seen_at'])
    duration = (date1-date2)
    print("Duration in seconds:", duration.seconds, duration.microseconds)
    print(x)
```

Esto es lo que contiene el json (activitites) y cómo debería quedar después de hacer el código (user_sessions).

```
{"activities": 
[ 
{ 
"id": 198891, 
"user_id": "emr5zqid", 
"answered_at": "2021-09-13T02:38:34.117-04:00", 
"first_seen_at": "2021-09-13T02:38:16.117-04:00" 
}, 

  
{ 
"user_sessions": { 
"3pyg3scx": [ 
{ 
"ended_at": "2021-09-10T19:51:26.799-04:00", 
"started_at": "2021-09-10T19:22:23.799-04:00", 
"activity_ids": [ 
251953, 
379044 
], 
"duration_seconds": 173.0 
}, 
{ 
"ended_at": "2021-09-11T04:33:50.799-04:00",
"started_at": "2021-09-11T04:05:20.799-04:00", 
"activity_ids": [
296400, 
247727, 
461955 
], 
"duration_seconds": 171.3 
} 
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice esto para poder agrupar.
Append para agregar los keys con los que quería trabajar, el print solo es para asegurarme que me imprima como quiero y al final usé itertools para poder agrupar,

```
user_sessions.append((x['user_id'], x['id'], difference_date))

print("User sessions: ", user_sessions)

for group in itertools.groupby(user_sessions, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    print(group[0], end=" -> Duration in secs: ")
    tot = datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)
    for session in group[1]:
        tot += session[2]
    if tot <= datetime.timedelta(seconds=300):
        print(tot.days*86400 + tot.seconds)
```